# Subtracting time difference between two rows MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
updated_on          | start_date

2017-09-28 21:09:05 | 2017-08-06 06:59:04

2017-10-02 15:19:05 | 2017-09-28 21:11:21

2017-10-05 12:00:00 | 2017-10-02 15:21:05
```

What i want to do is subtract the first instance of updated on with the second instance of start_date meaning

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 2017-09-28 21:09:05, 2017-09-28 21:11:21) 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 2017-10-02 15:19:05, 2017-10-02 15:21:05)
```

and continuously on like this if multiple rows exist.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: do you want only the dates or even time ?

Comment: What i want is the difference in second between the first row on updated_on and the second row on start_date, then the second row of updated_on and the third row for start_date etc.

Comment: Are you looking on something like cursors ?

Comment: perhaps. even if i can shift start date up one row on each value would help me fix my issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use a co-related subquery to get the next record.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , (SELECT
     start_date 
   FROM 
     Table1 table12
   WHERE
     Table1.updated_on < table12.updated_on
   ORDER BY 
     updated_on ASC 
   LIMIT 1
  ) 
   as next_start_date
FROM
 Table1
ORDER BY
 updated_on ASC
```

**Result (SQL fiddle)**

```
|           updated_on |           start_date |      next_start_date |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-09-28T21:09:05Z | 2017-08-06T06:59:04Z | 2017-09-28T21:11:21Z |
| 2017-10-02T15:19:05Z | 2017-09-28T21:11:21Z | 2017-10-02T15:21:05Z |
| 2017-10-05T12:00:00Z | 2017-10-02T15:21:05Z |               (null) |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94af3d/8

Now we can use TIMESTAMPDIFF function.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , TIMESTAMPDIFF(
       SECOND 
     , updated_on
     , (SELECT
         start_date 
        FROM 
         Table1 table12
        WHERE
         Table1.updated_on < table12.updated_on
        ORDER BY 
         updated_on ASC 
        LIMIT 1
       )
   ) as diff

FROM
 Table1
ORDER BY
 updated_on ASC
```

**Result**

```
|           updated_on |           start_date |   diff |
|----------------------|----------------------|--------|
| 2017-09-28T21:09:05Z | 2017-08-06T06:59:04Z |    136 |
| 2017-10-02T15:19:05Z | 2017-09-28T21:11:21Z |    120 |
| 2017-10-05T12:00:00Z | 2017-10-02T15:21:05Z | (null) |
```

demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94af3d/5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
     , TIMEDIFF(MIN(y.start_date),x.updated_on) n
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.updated_on > x.updated_on 
 GROUP 
     BY x.updated_on;
```

... or something like that